# Error: IOException - how to get more specific error

Tags: java, android

How to find out the more specific error situations like whether the error is because of `FileNotFoundException` , or `EOFExceptionor` `No Internet Access` etc....

below is the code that i am using to access the internet and i am getting the `IOException` and I know this is due to not having permission to access internet.. but how I want to know for SURE that whether this error related with file, or eof or permission related....

below is my code and catching all the exception but none will give me a specific situation exception.

```
try { 
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(MyConstants.URL);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    response = httpClient.execute(request);
    //HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
    xmlList = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    xmlList = "URL: is a malformed URL";
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    xmlList = "URL: UnsupportedEncodingException";
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    xmlList = "URL: ClientProtocolException"; 
} catch (SocketTimeoutException  e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    xmlList = "URL: SocketTimeoutException";
} catch (ConnectTimeoutException  e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    xmlList = "URL: ConnectTimeoutException";
} catch (IOException e) {
    xmlList = "URL: IOException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch it!

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    xmlList = "URL: FileNotFoundException";
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (EOFException e) {
    xmlList = "URL: EOFException";
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    xmlList = "URL: IOException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There is no such exception as 'No Internet Access'.

Comment: i know there is no such exception but i would like to know the cause of the `IOException`, get it?

Comment: @AbuHamzah The exception is its own cause. If you caught `FileNotFoundException` it was 'file not found'. If you caught `EOFException` it was EOF.